# Table of contents, large numbers, and fontspec

Tags: table-of-contents, fontspec

Somehow the table of contents large page numbers are not right-aligned when one uses a font different from the standard one, using XeLaTeX's *fontspec* package. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Bonum}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Foo}

\pagebreak
\setcounter{page}{100}
\subsection{Baz}

\end{document}
```

[image: Non-aligned page numbers]

The alignment is OK for smaller numbers (up to 99), but the number 100 in the above example is not right-aligned as it should be (and as it would be with the standard font).

Is there any work-around to this problem, preferably compatible with the *titletoc* package?

Comment: enlarge the place for the page number, the titletoc package has probably an option for it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you, that helped. I used *titletoc*'s contentsmargin command for that.